# Конвертация python(pycharm) проекта

Tags: python, pycharm, exe, project

как конвертировать весь проект в один .exe файл и как потом конвертировать .exe -> .dmg

используются посторонние библиотеки и модули

(.dmg это исполняемый файл для macOS, для тех кто не знал)

Comment: `.exe` – это расширение исполняемых файлов на операционной системе Windows, а не MacOS. Для тех, кто не знал **(:** Файлы `.dmg` это не исполняемые файлы, а образ диска, архив, упрощённо говоря.

Comment: `.exe` я конвертирую для винды, `.dmg` тоже можно использовать как исполняемый файл на macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть библиотеки и ПО, которые помогают собрать транслятор Питона и файлы проекта вместе, чтобы их можно было легко запускать и распространять:

- **PyInstaller** – позволяет собрать воедино проект на Windows, Mac OS X и GNU/Linux. [Документация](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)
- **py2app** – позволяет собрать проект в приложение МакОС `.app`. [Документация](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

<sub>Потенциально полезная ссылка: [похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7261795/5308802).</sub>

Образ `.dmg` с приложением или любым содержимым создать ещё проще, можно использовать системную программу Disk Utility, [вот инструкция](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-DMG-%D0%B2-Mac-OS).